# Create a table "alias", and change table type

Tags: php, mysql, full-text-search, alias

I have a table called **tb** which is innodb - has over 1m rows.

I want to do a fulltext search on the table, but I can't do that because its innodb.

So, How do I create an "alias" of **tb** called **tb2**, meaning *(a duplicate of the table, that updates automatically when the data of **tb** updates, but change the table type of **tb2** to myisam )*?

So, that way I can do a fulltext search on **tb2**, find the ids and SELECT the ids from **tb1**

Comment: Thanks for sharing. Please edit your post to include your question(s) about this.

Answer (score 4):

I personally think that this is not really a good idea because it will slow down writes and with the amount of data you have, your fulltext searches will be slow. I would sincerely recommend that you look into a dedicated full text search engine like Sphinx

http://sphinxsearch.com/

Answer (score 0):

- create a table with the same structure but myisam engine
- use triggers for INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE to maintain the consistent state between the two tables

But be careful, because it will make the write operations slower.

Comment: that is a solution to its specific problem, but the general problem is that that table has way too much data. Either sharding or another DB should be used specifically for text searching

Answer (score 0):

First, you would create a table using the following syntax:

```
create table tb2 like tb;
```

This creates a table with the same index structure as tb. Then, alter the table to make it myisam:

```
alter table tb2 engine='myisam';
```

Then, copy over the existing information:

```
insert into tb2 select * from tb;
```

In order to maintain the info, you would then need to create three triggers on tb... `after insert`, `after update`, and `after delete`. Each event would insert / update / delete the corresponding row in tb2.